# sorting a list - the best way possible

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I have a list

```
std::list<Selector> _selectorList;
```

I do parse on something and I get a smart pointer and a priority associated with the smart pointer. I implemented a structure to hold these two parameters like shown below.

```
struct Selector
{
    int priority;
    SmartPointer *selector;
}
```

There will be n number of parsing which will be done, as a result n number of struct instances will be pushed back into the list. At the end I am supposed to sort the list according to the decreasing order of priority variable in the structure. Currently, I plan to do this.

```
_selectorList.sort();
```

Is there any better approach than this, provided that I must use a list (only and nothing else) to store the smart pointers returned by parsing?

Comment: Where does this requirement come from? It seems silly enough to be homework.

Comment: Why do you _"must use a list (only and nothing else)"_?

Comment: I don't think you'll want a `SmartPointer *`. But what exactly is your problem with `std::list<T>::sort`?

Comment: Hi all, it might seem silly. My question is to know if there is a better approach. I never told there is anything wrong in this

Answer (score 3):

Like larsman told you using a pointer to a SmartPointer is highly probably wrong. Since smart pointers are used to avoid memory leaks, the reference counter is updated on object copy or assignment, so a SmartPointer * is probably useless.

For what concerne a better approach, you could reuse std::list::sort instead of reimplementing your own sort operation. The only things to do is let your Selector implement comparison operator in order to be able to sort your list.
Have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).